# Blocking batch_actions with ActiveAdmin and CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, activeadmin, cancan

I am using ActiveAdmin with Cancan for authorization.  In my ability model, I setup a user to only have read ability.  This works as expected, except the user can still select devices(the model I am restricting) and then perform a batch_update to edit one or more of them.  I can't block this in the view because that button is rendered by ActiveAdmin.

I tried something like this in the admin/devices controller..

```
if can? :manage
  collection_action :batch_update do
    blah blah
  end
end
```

But then I get undefined method `can?' for #

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display conditionally the block actions:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/9-batch-actions.md#conditional-display

Comment: Awesome, this link was very helpful!